# Select 2 Column 1 record as 1 column 2 records

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
name | place_1 | place_2
jhon | Tokyo   | Nagasaki
```

and I want it to be like this

```
name | place
jhon | Tokyo
Jhon | Nagasaki
```

How to Select it in SQL ?

Comment: You would already have the required result if you would have normalized your table..that would be a vertical design(just like your required output) instead of horizontally

Comment: `SELECT name, place1 place FROM my_table UNION SELECT name, place_2 FROM my_table`

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Comment: Ya , i am sorry , but thanks for help .. it fixed for me

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your expected output should have been your original table structure (and data). You should consider normalizing your data in first place.

Still, if you have no control over the table structure; you can use [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

```
(SELECT name, place_1 AS place
FROM your_table)

UNION ALL

(SELECT name, place_2 AS place
FROM your_table)

ORDER BY name, place DESC
```